# How to display closeable div covering the entire screen when tapping on a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a mobile web page with a table containing many rows. Each row has additional information. Ideally, when a user taps on each row, a new layer will display, covering the whole screen, that provides more information for each row. The layer can be closeable by tapping on the new layer itself.

Is this something I can do with a  to begin with? Or do these rows need to be divs instead? Please if someone could push me along, that would be excellent! Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried something already ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a lightbox that appear to do what you need.

You can load the content using ajax for exemple:

```
<a href="a link to a page with more information" class="lightbox">your row here</a>
```

Then pick a lightbox from a google search that you like and initialise it with your lightbox selector